# Laravel Backpack

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I need help. I am currently working with Laravel backpack and I have the following problem: I have a field called Media, that field has two behaviors, one to upload images and the other to write a URL, the problem is that it only lets me create the one time the field. Is there a way in laravel backpack to create 2 different fields with the same name?

I want to achieve something more or less like this:

CRUD::addField([ 'name' => 'url_media', 'label' => 'url_media', 'type' => 'upload',
]);

CRUD::addField([ 'name' => 'url_media', 'label' => 'url_media', 'type' => 'url', ]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the HTML spec, you cannot have two inputs with the same name in a form. I mean... you can. But only the last one will be sent in the request.

If you don't want to show both fields at the same time, you can use a conditional (if/else) to show either the `upload` field or the `url` field.

Otherwise, a different way would be to choose a fake name for the second field (say... `url_media_link`), then use a [Laravel Mutator](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator) in your model, in this case `setUrlMediaLinkAttribute()` to do what you manipulate the model attributes as you want.

Comment: Very valid, your comment in fact I tried the second way you tell me and I got an error. I was able to do it with a js code that changes the field type according to your selection